# BRD Wallet Recovery - Only have the first 11 words

Tags: wallet-recovery

I went to recover the wallet from my backup 12 word recovery phase, but it turns out I only have the first 11 words. The last word was replaced with the " character. I must have had the notepad file open, and leaned on the keyboard which replaced the last word in the list....and unfortunately saved it.

What can I do? Does having the first 11 words help me at all?

Comment: Sure, there's only a very small number of possibilities for the very last word. There'll be other advice here, but absolutely under no circumstance should you email with anybody offering private assistance or tools to download.

Answer (score 1):

Open source Bitcoin wallet password and seed recovery tool: https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover

Details about solving a problem involving bip 39 seed by brute forcing: https://medium.com/@johncantrell97/how-i-checked-over-1-trillion-mnemonics-in-30-hours-to-win-a-bitcoin-635fe051a752

[Similar questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=missing+word) with some good answers