# Know the words, forgot the order

Tags: passphrase

So have the words for sure but they were scrambled on paper... What are the options to getting back in my wallet? They started it oder I'm sure of but some word(s) are out of order

Answer (score 2):

If the question is about BIP 39 seed words, there are no duplicates and it has 12 words then possible permutations should be 12! which is 479001600. Example:

```
from itertools import permutations

def calculatePermutations(sentence):

    lis = list(sentence.split())
    permute = permutations(lis)

    for i in permute:

        permutelist = list(i)

        for j in permutelist:
            print(j, end = " ")

        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = "abandon ability able about above absent absorb abstract absurd abuse access accident"
    calculatePermutations(sentence)
```

[<sup>https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-possible-permutations-of-words-in-a-sentence/</sup>](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-possible-permutations-of-words-in-a-sentence/)

Related question: [BRD Wallet Recovery - Only have the first 11 words](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100463/brd-wallet-recovery-only-have-the-first-11-words/)